# replaceAll javascript

Tags: javascript, replace

I have this problem
I'm triyng to replace all the charachters like àòùèì with à ecc...

I have this prototype that works:

```
String.prototype.ReplaceAll = function(stringToFind,stringToReplace){
    var temp = this;
    var index = temp.indexOf(stringToFind);
        while(index != -1){
            temp = temp.replace(stringToFind,stringToReplace);
            index = temp.indexOf(stringToFind);
        }
        return temp;
    };
```

Now I want to use this prototype with my function called Clean:

```
function Clean(temp){
temp.ReplaceAll("è","&egrave;");
temp.ReplaceAll("à","&agrave;");
temp.ReplaceAll("ì","&igrave;");
temp.ReplaceAll("ò","&ograve;");
temp.ReplaceAll("ù","&ugrave;");
temp.ReplaceAll("é","&eacuta;");
return temp;
}
```

and now I want to use my function like this:

```
var name= document.getElementById("name").value;
var nomePul=Clean(name);
```

Why this does not work? What is wrong?

In this case it works (without my function clean, so I think the problem is there)

```
var nomePul=nome.ReplaceAll("è","&egrave;");
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: Instead of `temp.ReplaceAll("è", "&egrave;");`, the typical way to replace all instances of a string in Javascript is to use a regex: `temp.replace(/è/g, "&egrave;");`.

Comment: does not work either in this way:(

Comment: It does, but you need to use an assignment. Right now you're just throwing away the result of the returned function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following:

```
function Clean(temp){
temp=temp.ReplaceAll("è","&egrave;");
temp=temp.ReplaceAll("à","&agrave;");
temp=temp.ReplaceAll("ì","&igrave;");
temp=temp.ReplaceAll("ò","&ograve;");
temp=temp.ReplaceAll("ù","&ugrave;");
temp=temp.ReplaceAll("é","&eacuta;");
return temp;
}
```

You are not assigning the value

Comment: yes!!!!!! thanks!!! I give to you the correct answer because you was the first :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another implementation of replaceAll. Hope it helps someone.

```
    String.prototype.replaceAll = function (stringToFind, stringToReplace) {
        if (stringToFind === stringToReplace) return this;
        var temp = this;
        var index = temp.indexOf(stringToFind);
        while (index != -1) {
            temp = temp.replace(stringToFind, stringToReplace);
            index = temp.indexOf(stringToFind);
        }
        return temp;
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

ReplaceAll() returns a string. So you should do

```
temp = temp.ReplaceAll("è","&egrave;");
```

in your Clean() function

Answer (score 1):

The `ReplaceAll` function does not mutate the string. It returns a new string. That means you need to assign it, like this:

```
function Clean(temp){
    temp = temp.ReplaceAll("è","&egrave;");
    temp = temp.ReplaceAll("à","&agrave;");
    temp = temp.ReplaceAll("ì","&igrave;");
    temp = temp.ReplaceAll("ò","&ograve;");
    temp = temp.ReplaceAll("ù","&ugrave;");
    temp = temp.ReplaceAll("é","&eacuta;");
    return temp;
}
```

Note that prototype methods can be chained, so you could be slightly less repetitive if you did this:

```
function Clean(temp){
    return temp.ReplaceAll("è","&egrave;")
        .ReplaceAll("à","&agrave;")
        .ReplaceAll("ì","&igrave;")
        .ReplaceAll("ò","&ograve;")
        .ReplaceAll("ù","&ugrave;")
        .ReplaceAll("é","&eacuta;");
}
```

And if you like, you can use the typical way global replaces are done in Javascript instead, so then you don't need to use the custom `ReplaceAll` prototype function.

```
    return temp.replace(/è/g,"&egrave;")
        .replace(/à/g,"&agrave;")
        .replace(/ì/g,"&igrave;")
        .replace(/ò/g,"&ograve;")
        .replace(/ù/g,"&ugrave;")
        .replace(/é/g,"&eacuta;");
```

Answer (score 0):

you could apply this in 2 ways in javascript ..

1) Split and join strings array with your replaced string:

```
  return temp.split("è").join("&egrave;")
        .split("à").join("&agrave;")
        .split("ì").join("&igrave;")
        .split("ò").join("&ograve;")
        .split("ù").join("&ugrave;")
        .split("é").join("&eacuta;");
```

2) Using global replace that is built in javascript itself (As [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13276452/1334561) specified above)

```
return temp.replace(/è/g,"&egrave;")
        .replace(/à/g,"&agrave;")
        .replace(/ì/g,"&igrave;")
        .replace(/ò/g,"&ograve;")
        .replace(/ù/g,"&ugrave;")
        .replace(/é/g,"&eacuta;");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code to replace all. You can make function with this code.

```
var str = "Test abc test test abc test test test abc test test abc";
str = str.split('abc').join('');
alert(str);
```